# Multiple Logins, Python, Mechanize

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm using mechanize any python to log into a website and then iterate through a bunch of URLs. Those URLs are all behind a login-wall so I need to get logged in, then view many of the pages.

Challenge I'm facing:

- I'm hitting rate limits so I'm using a lot of time.sleep commands.
- I would like to be able to alternate my login credentials, say every 10 pages viewed.

As a very new python user and person who's generally new to web scraping, do you have advice on my code?

Does it make sense to login initially, and then view pages over and over or is there a better way to do that?

```
def get_Text_From_Links(inputFile,outputFile):
    with open(inputFile, "rU") as csvinput, open(outputFile, 'wb') as csvoutput :
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput)
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)

        br = mechanize.Browser()

        cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
        br.set_cookiejar(cj)

        br.set_handle_equiv(True)
        br.set_handle_gzip(True)
        br.set_handle_redirect(True)
        br.set_handle_refresh(False)  
        br.set_handle_referer(True)
        br.set_handle_robots(False)

        br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

        br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

        br.open('https://www.website.com/login')

        br.select_form(nr=0)

        br['username'] = 'login@gmail.com'
        br['password'] = 'pa$$w0rd'

        br.submit()


        for rownum, i in enumerate(reader):
            URL = i[6]
            if count == 10:
                time.sleep(15)
                count = 0
            else:
                count = count + 1
            try:
                br.open(URL)
            except urllib2.URLError:
                print "HTTP ERROR"

            html = br.response().read()

            if html.find('target text') != -1:
                v = 'text found'
                i.append(v)
                writer.writerow(i)
            else:
                v = 'text not found'
                i.append(v)
                writer.writerow(i)
```